# caller_method returns not the value, that i expected

Tags: ruby

I want to know, what method calls another method (I'm just trying to create simple expect("string").to eq("string") model (just like in RSpect, but more easier).

But i get "main", what is that? (I see that "main" for first time)

```rb
public

def expect(message)
  message.to_s
end

def to
  caller_method = caller_locations.first.label
  puts caller_method
end

expect("test").to #=> <main>
#what output i expected:
expect("test").to #=> expect
```

My goal:

```rb
#first i need to do something like that:
expect("test").to eq("test") #=> true
#final must look like this:
expect(expect("test").to eq("test")).to eq(true) #=> true
```

Comment: Can you share all the code in this file?  This seems like only part of it.

Comment: That's all code, i just started! :)
I need to create something like test that tests test (ouch):
expect(expect("test").to eq("test")).to eq(true) #=> true

But first i want to make something like:
expect("test").to eq("test") #=> true

Comment: `<main>` is the label Ruby uses for the "top level" of a file, i.e. outside of any class or method, which is where you're calling `expect("test").to`.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know about that. Thanks for answer @JordanRunning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend against using `caller_method` in this case. Rather, make a class whose methods return `self` - that way they will be chainable:

```
module Expectation
  attr_accessor :caller_method
  def expect(arg)
    self.caller_method = "expect"
    self
  end
  def to
    caller_method
  end
end

include Expectation

expect("foo").to
# => "expect"
```

Obviously this is only a starting point, and this doesn't actually do any comparisons / validations yet. But hopefully you can understand this pattern. The key thing is returning `self` to make a chainable API, and storing internal state using something like `attr_accessor`